# Rotating text using JQuery is flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a text rotator that uses speed and interval to determine how fast and when to rotate the text. Everything seems to be working ok, just the only issue I have is the flickering between the transitions. So in other words I can see the old and the new entry together. Can someone help me to avoid this?

My [JSFIDDLE is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld2t6qek/)

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //<![CDATA[
        (function($) {
            $.fn.rotator = function(settings) {
                settings = jQuery.extend({
                    interval: 5000,
                    speed:800,
                }, settings);

                return this.each(function() {
                    var $t = $(this),
                        $item = $t.children().addClass('item').hide();

                    $t.addClass('rotator');

                    if ($item.length > 1) {
                        $item.first().addClass('current').fadeIn(settings.speed);
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var c = $t.find('.current');
                            if (c.next().length === 0) {
                                c.removeClass('current').fadeOut(settings.speed);
                                $item.first().addClass('current').fadeIn(settings.speed);
                            } else {
                                c.removeClass('current').fadeOut(settings.speed).next().addClass('current').fadeIn(settings.speed);
                            }
                        }, settings.interval);
                    }
                });
            };
        })(jQuery);

        // Execute here!
        $(function() {
            $('#slider').rotator();
        });
        //]]> 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting everything into the callback function of `fadeOut()` works fine:

```
c.fadeOut(settings.speed, function () {
  $(this).removeClass('current')
         .next().addClass('current')
         .fadeIn(settings.speed)
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5p7dych6/**
**Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c6yrzsvr/**